# Hypothesis testing methods for time periods of differing lengths

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I am assisting with a study that follows a relatively simple pre-post design, outlined below. Our study consists of two groups: a control and a treatment. We have daily measurements from each participant for a period of 6 months before administration of the treatment/placebo as well as 10 days of daily measurements from each participant after administering the ‘treatment’. Our goal is to discover whether the treatment has a statistically significant impact on the values of the daily measurements across the two groups (specifically we want to know if the treatment decreases the values of these measurements as opposed to the control). We have tried ANOVA, two t-tests (one for within group differences, and another for across group), and are branching into regressions as we explore the data.

We have one last idea for our analysis, but are not sure if the method is possible/appropriate. We currently have been using averages/medians from the 10 day span, and comparing those to the averages/medians of the 6 month span with the help of the tests mentioned above. We are primarily utilizing medians in order to account for the unequal time periods, but we are still not confident that it is fair to do so. On the other hand, we were also considering taking all possible consecutive ten day spans from the 6 month baseline and taking the daily averages/medians within those spans. Then, we would take another final average/median of all the 10-day span averages/medians. In theory, this would allow us to compare our 10 day post treatment durations to an "average 10 day span" from their baseline 6 month period. Is this approach appropriate, and if so, how would we go about proving statistical significance? Would we be able to do the same tests as we tried above, or could we do something else such as testing whether "the participant's post treatment 10 day span stands out from the distribution of 10 day spans we see in the baseline”. If this is possible, would we be able to use medians of 10 day spans, or would means be more appropriate?

Comment: Have you considered a panel analysis (*e.g.*, a mixed model) with an indicator of the time of treatment?  Approaches like that use your data rather than information-reducing summaries of them and thereby are likely to be more powerful than the "average/median" approach you mention.